# Get url namespace path in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I got those patterns:

```
api_patterns = [
    ...
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(api_patterns, namespace='api')),
]
```

I would like to get the 'api' namespace path in a view,
so:

```
api_path = ??????
# api_path = 'api/v1/'
```

I've tried reverse function but got an error... any ideas?

Comment: Why? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I'd like to get the api prefix dynamically so if i use the path somewhere is my code, i wont have to find&replace it

Answer (score 0):

```
api_patterns = `[url(r'^foo/$',FooView.as_view(),'name='the_foo_details')]`
```

Then, to get the url:

```
reverse("api:the_foo_details")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?